# SQL CLR deployment for Sql Server 2012 Serializer issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, clr

I'm trying to execute a function created using CLR on a Sql Server 2012 database, I used VS2013 to create the function, the problem is that I invoke a web service to retrieve some data, as the SQL Server project does not allow to create sevices references I created a class library project into the solution, which is the one that make the call to the web service, everything works as expected, the function is created into the database, but when I try to execute it from SSMS I got the following error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate
>   "TestFunction":  System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot
>   load dynamically generated serialization assembly. In some hosting
>   environments assembly load functionality is restricted, consider using
>   pre-generated serializer. Please see inner exception for more
>   information. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: LoadFrom(), LoadFile(),
>   Load(byte[]) and LoadModule() have been disabled by the host.
>   System.IO.FileLoadException:     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadImage(Byte[] rawAssembly,
>   Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence evidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean fIntrospection, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[]
>   rawSymbolStore, Evidence securityEvidence)    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames)    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at Microsoft.CSharp.CShar   ...

So I have been googling it, and found several articles about this (I include only 4):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/11/25/how-to-consume-a-web-service-from-within-sql-server-using-sql-clr.aspx

http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2008/11/11/calling-a-web-service-from-sql-server-2005/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913668

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131088(v=sql.110).aspx

the thing is that all of them are working on VS2010 or SQL Server 2008, or are not using web services, basically the error that I'm getting is because as I am using a web service it needs a xml serializer so based on what I read, I used sgen.exe utility to create it, then I created the assembly on the sql server, just as the microsoft documentation says on its article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913668), but I still getting exactly the same error.

Comment: This just seems like a bad idea.  Why are you constrained to making a web service call from a sql server?  That seems like something that should happen in a different application.  Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.  If you had to do this then I would probably investigate using REST and the Newtonsoft Json Serializer.